# Put a section of an article into a category on Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I'd like to place sections of articles into categories on Wikipedia. (for example, placing "Pollution in India#Water pollution" into the category "Water pollution in India") Is there any way to do this besides creating a redirect page for the article and then putting the redirect page in the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say that I don't think doing this is a good idea. Category description pages on Wikipedia shouldn't contain article text, that's not what they're for. If you want to do this, make sure there is a consensus to do it. For some more information, see [*Creating category pages*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCategorization#Creating_category_pages).

If you're sure you want to do this, I think the only way (ignoring custom or some existing extension) is to use template transclusion. This can be done two ways:

If you know that you'll always want only this specific section, you can enclose it in [`<onlyinclude>` tag](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplate#Noinclude.2C_includeonly.2C_and_onlyinclude). Then you can transclude the article to the category page (e.g. `{{:Pollution in India}}`) and only this section will show up.

But if you want to transclude different sections of the same article to different categories, that won't work (unless you also added some `{{#if}}`s to the article, which I don't think is a good idea). What you can do then is to split the article into multiple parts, each within its own template. So, the text of the section *Water pollution* might be in `Template:Pollution in India/Water`. Then you can transclude that template to both the article and the category (using `{{Pollution in India/Water}}`).

Comment: Why isn't it a good idea to add {{#if}}s to the article?

Comment: "Normal" users should be able to edit articles. Because of that, articles shouldn't contain any overcomplicated markup.